# Play audio after a Time Interval IOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer

Hi in my application, audio is playing  when user press the button but now I have two audio buttons like audio1 and audio2, now I want to play second audio after a time interval once the audio1 is completed by clicking the same button.

```
     - (IBAction)btn1:(id)sender {
         NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audio" ofType:@"mp3" ];
         NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
         NSError *error;
         self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:&error];
         [self.audioPlayer play];
       }
```

The above code I have used for play one audio now I want to play second audio once the first audio completed please tell me how to make it.

Thanks.

Comment: you want to play first audio then second audio, each on a click and the second only if the first has finished?

Comment: @ReeCube ya exactly the same wt u said i want

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You have to add **a bool variable with the name 'firstAudioPlayed'** on start the variable should be **NO or FALSE**.

```
- (IBAction)btn1:(id)sender {
    if (![self.audioPlayer isPlaying]) {
        NSString *audioPath;
        if (self.firstAudioPlayed) {
            audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audio2" ofType:@"mp3" ];
        } else {
            audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audio1" ofType:@"mp3" ];
        }
        NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
        NSError *error;
        self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:&error];
        [self.audioPlayer play];
        self.firstAudioPlayed = !self.firstAudioPlayed;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's working like this, else just ask with a comment...

**Explication of the code:**

First you check if the player is already playing a song, if he isn't, you check if the first audio already has played (self.firstAudioPlayed) with this you can give the correct path to load the audio file. Now you play this audio file.

*(Sorry for my grammar and my english, corrections are welcome)*

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use player's delegate. Set `audioPlayer.delegate=self;` and implement `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:` method to see when a player finished playing.
Then you can do whatever you want in there, for example start the second audio.